# My deployment of a auto filter bot telegram is giving too much dependency version error

Tags: python

My requirements.txt fi.e contains-

**git+https://github.com/Joelkb/cinemagoer

pyrogram>=2.0.30

tgcrypto

pymongo[srv]
mongoengine

motor==3.1.1

marshmallow
umongo==3.0.1

requests

bs4

heroku3

pynewtonmath

pytz

aiohttp**

It is giving error -

This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Please recommend correct versions as I am not able to figure out